# How to convert this nested foreach in lambda/Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to convert this nested foreach in lambda/Linq expression to simplify the code?
How to convert this nested foreach in lambda/Linq expression to simplify the code?

```
LinkButtonContinue.Enabled = false;
foreach (OrderItem orderItem in order.OrderItemList)
{
    if (orderItem.OrderItemCommitAction.Equals(OrderItemCommitAction.Modify) ||
        orderItem.OrderItemCommitAction.Equals(OrderItemCommitAction.Cancel))
    {
        LinkButtonContinue.Enabled = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(OrderItem orderItemSLot in orderItem.OrderItemSlotList)
        {
            if (orderItemSLot.OrderItemCommitAction.Equals(OrderItemCommitAction.Modify) ||
            orderItemSLot.OrderItemCommitAction.Equals(OrderItemCommitAction.Cancel))
            {
                LinkButtonContinue.Enabled = true;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                LinkButtonContinue.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any LINQ or lambda here. What kind of "simplification" are you looking for? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, along with a detailed, precise description of what it is exactly that is unsatisfactory about that code, and how you want to address that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Func<OrderItem, bool> condition = 
    x => x.OrderItemCommitAction == OrderItemCommitAction.Modify ||
         x.OrderItemCommitAction == OrderItemCommitAction.Cancel;

LinkButtonContinue.Enabled =
    order.OrderItemList.Any(x => condition(x)) ||
    order.OrderItemList
         .SelectMany(x => x.OrderItemSlotList)
         .Any(x => condition(x));
```

**Edit:**

As per [@Mephy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3614521/mephy)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173547/how-to-convert-this-nested-foreach-in-lambda-linq-expression/32173602?noredirect=1#comment52233498_32173602),

> F(x => g(x)) is equivalent to F(g)

therefore this:

```
.Any(x => condition(x))
```

can be shortened to this:

```
.Any(condition)
```

Comment: Looks better in F# (like pretty much everything else) due to more advanced type inference and the pipe (`|>`) operator

Comment: Why the downvote, please?

Comment: It will return different results for certain input, because in the initial code once result was set to `true` it might be set to `false` again in next iteration of outer `foreach` loop. But I believe it's a bug in initial code which accidently got fixed by your solution.

Comment: `F(x => g(x))` is equivalent to `F(g)`.

Comment: @Mephy I know, but I wanted to show that in an explicit way for the OP

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek come to think about it, no, you're wrong. If the value is set to `true` it never goes back to `false` again, because there's a `break` right after. I deleted my edit about that.

Comment: @HighCore that `break` in inner loop only get's you out of that very inner `foreach`. You're still iterating in the outer `foreach`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek you're right. LOL, I guess the OP's code was wrong? seeing they accepted my answer... :P